# Store Execution history of CREATE, TRUNCATE and DROP statements in Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am working with an Azure SQL Database. I researched a lot but I can't find a way to store all the CREATE, TRUNCATE and DROP queries executed on my database. The Query Store only stores the SELECT etc... queries so that is also of no use.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: Query store doesn't store DDL queries. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver16#About): *"Query Store collects plans for DML Statements such as SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE, and BULK INSERT."*

Comment: Query store only collects data for statements with execution plans (DML queries not DDL primarily though `CREATE INDEX` and `CREATE STATISTICS` may show up)

Comment: ohhh shoot. Thanks for responding. So is there any way to store create querries?

Comment: No, because that isn't what Query Store is for; this smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: Got it @ThomA. Thanks for explaining the XY part. So is there any way to get history of Create, Drop, Truncate querries executed on an Azure SQL Database or should I post a new question?

Comment: You might as well just edit this one to ask about X as no one has answered it yet so it won't invalidate any answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK Azure SQL Database does not provide a built-in mechanism to capture all actions performed on the database, including data definition language (DDL) statements like CREATE, TRUNCATE, and DROP queries, you can use Azure SQL Auditing and Log Analytics to capture and analyze this information.  To enable Audits on server level, go to auditing option in server and click on enable and select where need to store the logs like storage account, log analytics, event hubs and click on save.

[image]

After that go to database level and select auditing and follow above procedure to enable audits.

[image]

I executed create and drop command on database

```
create table emp(ID int,Name varchar(20))
Drop table emp
```

These logs are stored in selected storage account.

[image]